# Google maps - storing application-defined data in path

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In my app I want to store application-defined data on each latLng in a path.
I have got this to work using the code example below, but I would like to know whether this is an undocumented fluke that just 'happens' to work and could get broken in the future, or is it perfectly valid code that should always work?
In short, is 'getPath' guaranteed to return the same latLng objects that were passed in, or can it pass back new ones with the same lat and the same lng but anything else that google doesn't care about might not still be there?

Thanks for any assistance

Click on the line, and it should alert "one  two  three".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0, -1.5),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            strokeColor: "blue",
            strokeThicknedss: 2
        });

        polyline.setPath([
            getLatLng(51.9, -1.4, "one"),
            getLatLng(52.0, -1.5, "two"),
            getLatLng(52.0, -1.6, "three")
        ]);

        google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {
            var path = this.getPath().getArray();
            var datas = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                var ll = path[i];
                datas.push(ll.data);
            }
            alert(datas.join("\n"));
        });
      }

      function getLatLng(lat, lng, data) {
        var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        ll.data = data;
        return ll;
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well [according to the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) getPath() '*retrieves the first path*'.  And you've just set the path using setPath()... I'm not sure Google are going to mess with that data; your approach seems sound to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way for storing polylines is to use Google's encoding function in the geometry library.

```
var polylineToStore = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(polyline.getPath());
```

This sets the polylineToStore variable to a string. When you want to reuse that encoded polyline you only need to decode it:

```
polyline.setPath(google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(polylineToStore))
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Encoding